# Can the referred object of 'this' keyword change without a new operator or calling apply()/call() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm studying how to make jquery plugins.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Study</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($, undefined) {
    function MyPlugin() {
        this.myoption = "myvalue";
    }

    $.extend(MyPlugin.prototype, {
        _attachMyPlugin: function(target, settings) {
            console.log(this); // check2
        }
    });

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        console.log(this); // check1
        $.myPlugin._attachMyPlugin(this, options);
        return this;
    };

    $.myPlugin = new MyPlugin(); // singleton instance
}(jQuery));
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#abc").myPlugin();
});
</script>
<h1 id="abc">title1</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why the value of `this` changes when I call _attachMyPlugin().
At check1 `this` seems to refer just a jQuery object. It doesn't seem to be strange for me.
However at check2 'this' seems to refer MyPlugin object. Why?

Can the referred object of `this` keyword change without a `new` operator or calling `.apply()` / `.call()` function? if so why?

Here is the result from Chrome console.

> [h1#abc, context: document, selector: "#abc", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
>    w.html:21
>   MyPlugin {myoption: "myvalue", _attachMyPlugin: function}
>    w.html:16

Comment: It didn't change. `this` is still the `MyPlugin` instance at check2 as it should be. It won't be the element unless you apply or call it.

Comment: Precisely, it could be changed like Tibos metioned below. I tried it. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually inside a function, the value of this is the object the function is called on:

```
var a = {
  b : { 
    c : function() {
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
};

a.b.c() // this will be a.b

var d = {};
d.e = a.b.c;

d.e() // this will be d

var f = a.b.c;

f() // this will be the global object (usually window) or undefined (strict mode)
```

Obviously `call` and `apply` allow you to override that and pass other objects to the function. There is one more notable exception: `bind`. Bind creates a new function which is always called on the object passed to bind. It acomplishes this by using `apply` (check MDN for an approximate implementation).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Applied on your code:

```
$("#abc").myPlugin(); // check1 this is $("#abc")

$.myPlugin._attachMyPlugin(this, options); // check2 this is $.myPlugin (which is an instance of MyPlugin)
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` only changes for a function when it is being used with .apply or .call, if it is an event, or if it is taken out of context (more on that in a bit).

For example, we have this code:

```
var foo = {
    myFunction: function(){
        console.log(this);
    },
    bar: "foobar"
}
```

As long as we execute `myFunction` as a property of `foo` and not with apply or call, `this` will be `foo`.

```
foo.myFunction(); // foobar
foo.bar = "Hello World!";
foo.myFunction(); // Hello World!
```

Now, if we bound a click event and set it's handler to `foo.myFunction`, `this` would  become the element.

```
$("#abc").click(foo.myFunction); // HTMLDomNode (after a click)
```

Now, if you stored `foo.myfunction` in another variable and then executed it, `this` would be the window because that reference of it is no longer part of `foo`.

```
var bar = foo.myFunction;
bar(); // window
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9V9S7/

Answer (score 0):

$.myPlugin - the instance of MyPlugin class. And method _attachMyPlugin() belongs to MyPlugin instance. When you call this method, "this" points to $.myplugin object.
When you call $.fn.someFunction, "this" points to jQuery object, $("#abc")